# prove for integrals of arcsin inverse trigonometry function

Tags: trigonometry

I had difficulty understanding the formula of integrals of arcsin inverse trigonometry function

[image]

I did some research and played around the formula, and finally seem to have proved it. I took a screenshot of my work, just in case anyone else is having trouble understanding the formula and require some prove

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$(\arcsin x)'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

then by chain rule

$$(\arcsin f(x))'=\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-(f(x))^2}}$$

with $f(x)=\frac x a$.

Comment: thanks for the tip, definitely something worth remembering :)

Comment: @Thor The best way to check integration is take the derivative! You are welcome, Bye.